# Objective C AES CBC Encryption with Zero Padding

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, aes, cbc-mode

I am trying to encrypt a string with AES 128 encryption, using CBC mode, with Zero Padding. Sadly, i do not know how to do this, as many attempts have gone unsuccessful. I have code in C# and was wondering whether anyone can help me getting my encryption working. 
the code:

```
`using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

byte[] request = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{string which needs encrypting}");

byte[] key = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{key}");
byte[] iv = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{iv}");

AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();

aes.Key = key;
aes.IV = iv;


aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

ICryptoTransform cTransform = aes.CreateEncryptor();

byte[] result = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(request, 0, request.Length);

aes.Clear()

string encryptedRequest = Convert.ToBase64String(result, 0, result.Length);`
```

ive looked a common crypto, but i cannot see an option to CBC mode [i dont know cccrypto much anyways, maybe i overlook?] 
thanks;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Method in `CommonCrypto.m`

```
- (NSData *) dataEncryptedUsingAlgorithm: (CCAlgorithm) algorithm
                                 key: (id) key
                initializationVector: (id) iv
                             options: (CCOptions) options
                               error: (CCCryptorStatus *) error
```

iv parameter declaration

> ```
> @param      iv              Initialization vector, optional. Used for 
>                             Cipher Block Chaining (CBC) mode. If present, 
>                             must be the same length as the selected 
>                             algorithm's block size. If CBC mode is
>                             selected (by the absence of any mode bits in 
>                             the options flags) and no IV is present, a 
>                             NULL (all zeroes) IV will be used. This is 
>                             ignored if ECB mode is used or if a stream 
>                             cipher algorithm is selected.
> ```

so , you could pass `nil` value to `iv` parameter

Answer (score 2):

[Common Crypto](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/CCCryptorCreate.3cc.html) is the right place to look. Specifically, you want to use the 3rd parameter of CCCryptorCreate, which is CCOptions set to 0. That is, the default is CBC. You should open up CommonCrypto.h, as it's actually better documentation than the man page. Here's an example of how to do it:

```
CCCryptorRef cryptorRef;
CCCryptorStatus rc;
rc = CCCryptorCreate(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, 0, key, keySize, NULL, &cryptorRef);
```

I passed in NULL for the IV (which means all zeros) and assumed you got the key and key size setup correctly. In my test, I used a 32 byte (256 bit) key.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the following links.

[AES1](https://github.com/dev5tec/FBEncryptor)
[AES2](https://github.com/rnapier/RNCryptor)
[AES3](https://github.com/Amnysia/Encryption-AES-Category)

You can download source code library from there and use it in your project if you find any of them useful for you.